# mysql soap calling is not worked on android device

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, android-emulator, ksoap2

i have developed one login form in android application calling mysql database calling soap webservices.it is worked successfully on android emulator.But not worked on android real device.please what can i do.please explain whats happened here.

my android code is:

```
package com.androidlogin.ws;
import java.net.SocketException;
import android.util.Log;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
private final String URL = "http://111.223.128.10:8085/AndroidLogin/services/Login?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  loginAction();

  }
  });
  }

    private void loginAction(){
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
     ServiceConnection connection = getServiceConnection();
        connection.connect();
    try{
      connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
           result.setText(response.toString());

    }


   catch(SocketException ex)
     {
   Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
     ex.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
    protected ServiceConnection getServiceConnection() throws IOException {
     return new AndroidServiceConnection(URL);
      }

      }
```

displayed dis message on my logout window:
07-20 04:26:22.728: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

But my my ip address.port number all are correct only.

Comment: post your code, what exception you getting

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

You also need to catch this Exception:

```
 catch(SocketException ex)
       {
         Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

**UPDATE**

Try adding following permissions in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**EDIT**

Add few lines of code before try block:

```
    ServiceConnection connection = getServiceConnection();
    connection.connect();
```

Inside try block, write this:

```
     connection.setConnectTimeout(60000); //put a large value for timeout
```

create the following method:

```
     protected ServiceConnection getServiceConnection() throws IOException {
        return new AndroidServiceConnection(url);
    }
```

Run the code again and try now.

Comment: i have added ur code..please see my code part now.in dis line have error:catch(SocketException ex).the error is:Multiple markers at this line
 - Unreachable catch block for SocketException. It is already handled by the catch block for 
  Exception
 - Line breakpoint:AndroidWSDLFrontEnd [line: 41] - onCreate(Bundle)....please how is clear dis error

Comment: remove the 1st catch block and try. Make sure your braces are closed correctly

Comment: it is affecting my try block...please see again my update code.because am missing 1st catch block code.now ly inserted.

Comment: make change over here : catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("ERROR: "   + e.getClass().getName() + ":" + e.getMessage());

    }

Comment: i have change my code.but it is affecting my try block. androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
above line have to displayed following error:Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type IOException
 - Unhandled exception type 
  XmlPullParserException

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045990/do-i-have-to-include-catch-blocks-in-java-when-calling-a-method-that-throws-exce and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747161/connecting-to-web-service-with-ksoap2-getting-xmlpullparserexception

Comment: i have change the code     catch (SocketException E) {
E.printStackTrace();
((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("ERROR: "   + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}...now error is cleared.but i run d application on my android real device.the below error is diplayed Java.net.SocketException:The operation timed out.

Comment: now also displayed dis error on my device net.SocketException:The operation timed out.

Comment: my emulator is 2.2.but my android device is 2.2.1.but the above code is worked above 2.2 version on emulator

Comment: see my answer again...i feel now it should work properly..i got my output correctly

Comment: added dis line connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);.displayed below error The method setConnectTimeout(int) is undefined for the type 
 ServiceConnection

Comment: added that service connection method also..dis line have displayed dis message:Multiple markers at this line
 - AndroidServiceConnection cannot be resolved to a type
 - Line breakpoint:AndroidLoginExampleActivity [line: 217] - getServiceConnection()
 - AndroidServiceConnection cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: ok remove that completely...just check whether your server is up and running fine..i will try and find solution for this and tell u...please email me later ur code